# How can I properly use 'mvn release:prepare'?

Tags: git, maven, maven-plugin, release, maven-release-plugin

I tried this command (with `dryrun` to test) on my Maven project:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare -DdryRun=true -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -Dtag=solocal-refentreprive-2.1-RC02 -DreleaseVersion=2.1-RC02 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.1-SNAPSHOT
```

At the end, the build is a success, but I have (in my commit) many `pom.next` / `pom.tag` and `pom.backUp`...

I don't when then (`-DgenerateBackupPoms=false`), if I use without `dryrun`. I don't want to push this [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model)...

Comment: What version of Maven? What version of the maven release plugin?

Comment: Several of the tags seem improper; e.g. what has this to do with git?

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger: *"my commit"* and *"to push"*  may refer to [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), but it is very vague. In any case, it ***seems*** irrelevant.

Comment: It is incomprehensible near *"I don't when then"*. For example, are one or more words missing? Can you fix it?

Comment: arg... almost 6 years ago... i dont remember :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you accept the defaults `release:prepare` performs the following

1. build and check all tests pass
2. check there are no `SNAPSHOT` dependencies
3. change the version from `x.x-SNAPSHOT` to `x.x`
4. push to a tag in SCM
5. change the version for the next iteration to `x.(x+1)-SNAPSHOT`

So your `pom.backUp` is the original pom, your `pom.tag` is from step 3 and your `pom.next` is from step 5.

You can clean up with a `mvn release:clean` which will be done automatically after a `release:perform` see [maven-release](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/clean-mojo.html)

Comment: push a tag means pushing to git or just creating a local tag which needs to be explicitly pushed ?

Comment: @SharadHolani means pushing the tag to the remote SCM

Comment: I run the maven release plugin.  But I dont see any new tags being pushed to my remote git. I can see that it has made 2 local commits as described in step 3 and 5. Also, I can see the tag being created locally when I run git describe --tags. Don't I need to run git push to push that tag created in step 4 to remote git ?

Answer (score 5):

Based on your question, you haven't run `mvn release:perform` after the `mvn release:prepare` command.

Don't forget to finish your release process with the perform command.
*[Plugin Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/plugin-info.html)*

Or if you don't want to use *perform*, use should the `mvn release:clean` again.