# How to increase snapshot version or release version automatically through maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3

How to increase snapshot version or release version automatically through maven. I am aware we could use maven goals such as release:prepare or release:update-versions. But i have a scenario where my snapshot version or release version should increment automatically for each build. Should we add any custom line code in pom.. please suggest me a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? The Maven release plugin (`release-prepare`, `release-perform`) does update the version automatically.

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472914/how-to-use-properly-mvn-releaseprepare/43473455?r=SearchResults&s=3|26.1747#43473455)

Comment: I would suggest to take a look into https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: JF Meier - Automatically means i meant each time i generate a build, the version or release number should increment itself

Comment: Guys thanks for your suggestions.. but i am generating my build through Jenkins.. so will the release:prepare or release:update-versions work there ? please suggest since i am very new  to this ci/cd env

Comment: See my link which can give the build number via command line...

Comment: @khmarbaise - i think you mis-understood.I am not generating build through command line. I have a Jenkins file and i am generating my build through Jenkins.

Comment: Yes I understood. But of course you can give the buildnumber of jenkins into the pipeline through jenkins into the build of Maven which handles the versions in your Maven build...